# Image Compression Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, image-compression

I want to compress my image to less than 500kb, which may be taken from camera or gallery. I tried a lot of code in google but nothing provides a good result. Please help me out to…

Answer (score 1):

You can use this...

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(<#Image data#>, <#Value#>)
```

Value should be between 0.1 (Lowest compression) and 1.0 (Highest compression). When you place 0 then it will take device scale which may be retina or non-retina resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *imgData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0f);
NSLog(@"1.0 size: %d", imgData1.length);

NSData *imgData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.7f);
NSLog(@"0.7 size: %d", imgData2.length);

NSData *imgData3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.4f);
NSLog(@"0.4 size: %d", imgData3.length);

NSData *imgData4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.0f);
NSLog(@"0.0 size: %d", imgData4.length);
```

Usage

```
UIImage *reducedImage = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData2];
```